# deleting rows with irrelevant scale values in text file

Tags: python-3.x

after manipulation of a text file including coordinates and field measurements i am left with a 3 column text file of coordinates(x,y) and a third column of scale. due to field recording issues some of these values are not relevant and appear as either 1 or 9, trying to find a way to erase the rows containing these values (appear many times sporadically in a large scale file)

this is small sample from one of these many files:

```
+016.938000 -33.120000 -31.77
+016.938000 -33.120000 -29.94
+016.937000 -33.120000 -31.39
+016.937000 -33.120000 -32.51
+016.936000 -33.120000 -31.66
+016.936000 -33.120000 -31.02
+016.935000 -33.120000 -31.66
+016.935000 -33.120000 -32.41
+016.934000 -33.120000 9
+016.933000 -33.120000 -30.85
+016.933000 -33.120000 -31.61
+016.932000 -33.120000 -30.25
+016.932000 -33.120000 -30.85
+016.931000 -33.120000 -31.98
+016.931000 -33.120000 -31.01
+016.930000 -33.120000 -31.82
+016.930000 -33.120000 -32.04
+016.929000 -33.120000 -30.42
+016.928000 -33.120000 -30.69
+016.928000 -33.120000 -32.57
+016.900000 -33.130000 -31.51
+016.899000 -33.130000 -31.51
+016.899000 -33.130000 -31.51
+016.898000 -33.130000 -31.51
+016.898000 -33.130000 1
+016.897000 -33.130000 1
+016.897000 -33.130000 1
+016.896000 -33.130000 1
+016.896000 -33.130000 1
+016.895000 -33.130000 -31.51
+016.613000 -33.230000 19.75
+016.610000 -33.230000 19.81
+016.609000 -33.230000 19.62
+016.608000 -33.230000 19.50
+016.608000 -33.240000 19.31
+016.607000 -33.240000 19.50
+016.607000 -33.240000 19.50
+016.606000 -33.240000 19.06
+016.606000 -33.240000 18.94
+016.605000 -33.240000 19.25
+016.605000 -33.240000 18.62
+016.604000 -33.240000 19.00
+016.602000 -33.240000 19.00
+016.602000 -33.240000 17.69
+016.601000 -33.240000 17.81
```

i have tried this method:

```
    with open(after_columns) as In, open(coord_with_scale, 'w') as Out:
        new_f = In.readlines()
        In.seek(2)
        for line in new_f:
            if " 1" not in line or " 9" not in line:
                Out.write(line)
```

but it deletes al scale numbers starting with a 1 or 9 (19, 91 etc.)

i have also tried

```
    with open(after_columns) as In, open(coord_with_scale, 'w') as Out:
        new_f = In.readlines()
        In.seek(2)
        for line in new_f:
            if " 1 " not in line or " 9 " not in line:
                Out.write(line)
```

but since the 9 and 1 are the end of the row it does not read them in this way

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your file is pretty well-behaved, with 3 whitespace-delimited fields per line. In that case, you just need to check the third value:

```
with open(after_columns) as In, open(coord_with_scale, 'w') as Out:
    for line in In:
        if line.strip().split()[2] not in ('1', '9'):
            Out.write(line)
```